# A single HDD stops working in USB 2 enclosure

Tags: hard-drive, usb, partitioning, external-hard-drive, sata

I have a WD hard drive that simply refuses to be read when put in a WD enclosure for SATA to USB 2. The drive shows up in macOS, Ubuntu and Windows, but appears uninitialized/unpartitioned.

#### Here are the details:

- Fails to read on three separate machines: Raspberry Pi 4, PC laptop, MacBook Air.
- Fails to read properly in Linux, macOS and Windows.
- The drive itself works fine (read, write) using another, vertical SATA to USB 3 dock, as well as internal SATA connectors on a fourth machine.
- Another, *identical* drive, purchased at the same time, works fine with the problematic enclosure in question. A third unrelated drive also works with the enclosure.
- Two USB cables tested, yielding the same results.

#### Additional details

- The problematic drive is a 1TB WD10EADS.
- The enclosure is a WD Elements P/N WDBAAU0020HBK-01
- The enclosure originally came with a 2TB drive, i.e twice the size.
- Both MBR and GPT drives seem to work with the enclosure — just not this drive.
- There does not appear to be any problems with the partition table. For one it works using other interfaces, as mentioned, and at that point `fdisk` finds no problems, and `gdisk` sees it as pure MBR.

I'm having a hard time figuring out what I've overlooked. What I've done so far suggests that there's no problem with the drive nor the enclosure, and that there isn't a problem with the pairing of the enclosure with this particular HDD model.

Can I do any other tests to understand what the problem is?

---

#### Update dec 24 (more details)

- The original drive for the enclosure is presumed killed by ‍⬛ and plays no part in this question.
- The enclosure is powered. The power supply measures a stable 12 V (under no significant load).
- The drives have no -- nor have ever had -- any jumpers. For those interested, on this model the jumper pins provide the features "Spread Spectrum Clocking", "Power Up In Standby" and "1.5GB PHY".

##### `fdisk -l` for the two same-model drives in the working SATA to USB 3 dock:

###### Non-working drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdc: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: EADS-00L5B1     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x6f300962

Device     Boot     Start        End   Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdc1  *         2048  208898047 208896000  99.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc2       208898048  415746047 206848000  98.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc3       642889170 1501813170 858924001 409.6G  7 HPFS/NTFS/exFAT
/dev/sdc4       415748094  642888295 227140202 108.3G  f W95 Ext'd (LBA)
/dev/sdc5       529319936  642888295 113568360  54.2G 83 Linux

Partition table entries are not in disk order.
```

Standard error output:

```
Partition 3 does not start on physical sector boundary.
Partition 4 does not start on physical sector boundary.
```

###### Working drive:

```
Disk /dev/sdd: 931.51 GiB, 1000204886016 bytes, 1953525168 sectors
Disk model: EADS-00L5B1     
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes
Disklabel type: gpt
Disk identifier: 12B5A74F-A8D5-4556-AF05-6CB2229DCBA0

Device          Start        End    Sectors   Size Type
/dev/sdd1        2048 1134325759 1134323712 540.9G Microsoft basic data
/dev/sdd2  1134325760 1953521663  819195904 390.6G Microsoft basic data
```

If the request for "`fdisk -l` in both cases" means "...in both enclosures" then this is the output with the non-working enclosure:

```
fdisk: cannot open /dev/sdc: Input/output error
```

#### Update 25 dec

- The original drive for the enclosure is a WD20EARX-00PASB0, i.e. a WD Caviar Green, just like the problem drive.
- Both the original drive and the problematic one are "512e" according to a price comparison site (the only source I could find for that info — I sure didn't see it in the official product data sheet which is itself impossible to find without resorting to third party sites)
- Using a working drive in the problematic enclosure `fdisk -l` still reports that both logical and physical sectors are 512 in size, just like when using the USB 3 dock or the internal SATA connection. I don't understand in what way the enclosure changes the sector sizes, if it does.
- The `fdisk` reported "I/O size" **does** change between interfaces, but the phrase "I/O size" is extremely vague and I can't find any explanation of that field in the fdisk manual, rendering it meaningless to me. [This definition](https://unix.stackexchange.com/a/598392/109837) leaves me none the wiser since in my eyes that's just the definition of the logical sector size.
- The identical working drive seems to "work" in the enclosure to the extent that macOS detects and mounts a volume on it, after which I concluded it was "working". Now it seems that macOS only sees *one out of two partitions* on it using the enclosure (!). See `fdisk -l` output below.

##### `fdisk -l` of "working" identical drive in enclosure:

```
GPT PMBR size mismatch (1953525167 != 1953519615) will be corrected by write.
Disk /dev/sdb: 931.51 GiB, 1000202043392 bytes, 1953519616 sectors
Disk model: Ext HDD 1021    
Units: sectors of 1 * 512 = 512 bytes
Sector size (logical/physical): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
I/O size (minimum/optimal): 512 bytes / 512 bytes
Disklabel type: dos
Disk identifier: 0x00000000

Device     Boot Start        End    Sectors   Size Id Type
/dev/sdb1           1 1953519615 1953519615 931.5G ee GPT
```

In words, the working drive + enclosure can be read properly but does not appear to expose a usable partition table on Linux. This seems like a tangential problem perhaps explained by the Advanced Format answers below. Compare this output with using it in the USB 3 dock above, where it exposes a working partition table: the sector sizes are the same but "I/O size" isn't: `I/O size (minimum/optimal): 4096 bytes / 4096 bytes`. Once again it's not at all clear what "I/O size" even means, making it difficult to form a proper understanding of the situation and make any use of the `fdisk` output. We'll leave this problem here though, since it's not the focus of this question.

##### `dmesg -w` comparison when plugging in the enclosure

###### The working drive

```
[ 2253.906554] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 7 using xhci_hcd
[ 2254.055583] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021, bcdDevice=20.21
[ 2254.055605] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2254.055612] usb 3-1: Product: Ext HDD 1021
[ 2254.055617] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 2254.055622] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 574341553437333531363634
[ 2254.059918] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2254.061302] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 2255.073051] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Ext HDD 1021     2021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2255.074288] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2255.074871] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953519616 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 2255.076423] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2255.076430] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 17 00 10 08
[ 2255.077935] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 2255.077942] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2255.107533] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

###### The non-working drive

```
[ 2428.062663] usb 3-1: new high-speed USB device number 8 using xhci_hcd
[ 2428.211750] usb 3-1: New USB device found, idVendor=1058, idProduct=1021, bcdDevice=20.21
[ 2428.211773] usb 3-1: New USB device strings: Mfr=1, Product=2, SerialNumber=3
[ 2428.211781] usb 3-1: Product: Ext HDD 1021
[ 2428.211786] usb 3-1: Manufacturer: Western Digital
[ 2428.211791] usb 3-1: SerialNumber: 574341553437333731323230
[ 2428.217156] usb-storage 3-1:1.0: USB Mass Storage device detected
[ 2428.217966] scsi host7: usb-storage 3-1:1.0
[ 2429.245027] scsi 7:0:0:0: Direct-Access     WD       Ext HDD 1021     2021 PQ: 0 ANSI: 4
[ 2429.246381] sd 7:0:0:0: Attached scsi generic sg1 type 0
[ 2429.246863] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] 1953519616 512-byte logical blocks: (1.00 TB/932 GiB)
[ 2429.248354] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Write Protect is off
[ 2429.248358] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Mode Sense: 17 00 10 08
[ 2429.249861] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] No Caching mode page found
[ 2429.249868] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Assuming drive cache: write through
[ 2429.254561] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.254570] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.254575] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.254579] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.254582] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.254590] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.255141] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.255147] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.255152] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.255156] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.255159] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.255166] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.255680] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.255685] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.255690] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.255694] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.255696] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.255703] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.255716] ldm_validate_partition_table(): Disk read failed.
[ 2429.256223] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.256228] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.256233] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.256237] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.256239] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.256245] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.256765] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.256770] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.256775] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.256778] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.256781] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.256787] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.257305] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.257309] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.257314] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.257318] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.257320] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.257326] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.261410] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.261420] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.261425] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.261430] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.261432] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.261441] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.261460] Dev sdb: unable to read RDB block 0
[ 2429.262000] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.262006] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.262011] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.262015] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.262017] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.262024] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.262578] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.262584] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.262589] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.262593] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 00 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.262595] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 0 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.262602] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 0, async page read
[ 2429.263143] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 FAILED Result: hostbyte=DID_OK driverbyte=DRIVER_OK cmd_age=0s
[ 2429.263151] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Sense Key : Data Protect [current] 
[ 2429.263156] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 Add. Sense: Logical unit access not authorized
[ 2429.263160] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] tag#0 CDB: Read(10) 28 00 00 00 00 18 00 00 08 00
[ 2429.263162] critical target error, dev sdb, sector 24 op 0x0:(READ) flags 0x0 phys_seg 1 prio class 0
[ 2429.263169] Buffer I/O error on dev sdb, logical block 3, async page read
[ 2429.264241]  sdb: unable to read partition table
[ 2429.264353] sd 7:0:0:0: [sdb] Attached SCSI disk
```

##### `hdparm -I` of faulty drive

```
/dev/sdc:

ATA device, with non-removable media
Standards:
    Likely used: 1
Configuration:
    Logical     max current
    cylinders   0   0
    heads       0   0
    sectors/track   0   0
    --
    Logical/Physical Sector size:           512 bytes
    device size with M = 1024*1024:           0 MBytes
    device size with M = 1000*1000:           0 MBytes 
    cache/buffer size  = unknown
Capabilities:
    IORDY not likely
    Cannot perform double-word IO
    R/W multiple sector transfer: not supported
    DMA: not supported
    PIO: pio0
```

Comment: You say the drive is WD and the enclosure is WD, but is the enclosure the same one used by the drive? Or is this another WD enclosure? Because if it works in another USB to SATA device as well as the internal SATA connections, then it all points to an incompatibility of the enclosure. Also, is that enclosure powered? That could be the issue if the enclosure is unpowered.

Comment: Can you add the outputs of `fdisk -l` in both cases?

Comment: @TomYan Not relevant. Please read the third point under the heading “Here are the details:” which reads, “The drive itself works fine (read, write) using another, vertical SATA to USB 3 dock, as well as internal SATA connectors on a fourth machine.” So the issue is not the drive, but the USB2 to SATA enclosure.

Comment: @Giacomo1968 and why do you think `fdisk -l` is all about the drive itself? The point was to see if there's a change in logical block size / number of blocks between the two cases, and whether the MBR / partition table is entirely invisible in the not working case. It's not a SMART scan that I asked for / it would do.

Comment: Hmm okay so I missed the fact that an identical drive works with the enclosure. While you get I/O error when `fdisk -l`, does SCSI read capacity work at all? (I mean like, with `dmesg -w` running, what's the new output do you can when you plug the non-working drive+enclosure in?)

Comment: One big problem here is that the non-working enslosure somehow reports a wrong disk size (`1953519616` instead of `1953525168`) for both identical drives. Unless you have the reason and solution for it, I'd say you should probably stop trying to get it work. (I haven't really check what exactly you are asked to do in the modification / hacking answer but I suppose it's probably one of the best shots for your final attempt.)

Comment: "The original drive for the enclosure is presumed killed by ‍⬛ and plays no part in this question." - Point is, as it was used to partition/format non working drive, it DOES play role if it was setup to emulate 4 K sectors. Dump sector 2048 to binary file and share please.

Comment: @JoepvanSteen I'm afraid I'm not sure exactly what you're requesting. Sector 2048 of which drive? It doesn't play a part in the question as in "none of the drives in the question are the original drive".

Comment: @TomYan That's a good observation. I missed that. Weird thing is that the 1 TB drive has a discrepancy of 5552 sectors, and my third (500 GB) test drive has a discrepancy of 4144 sectors. It's as if they put a drive with bad sectors in the enclosure and compensated in the USB adapter firmware, with 4144 of them in the first 500 GB... Well, that's the limit of my imagination.

Comment: You are probably referring to size (+1) of the `ee` partition in `fdisk -l`. The size there is probably the "corrected" size of the PMBR (see the PMBR size mismatch error), i.e., it's not even the data/value found on the drive. Instead the "corrected" size is derived (by `fdisk`) from the reported size (-1, as LBA 0 itself is not covered by the partition entry). The reported size is a value found in the response for the SCSI READ CAPACITY command (which is translated to relevant ATA commamd by the bridge in the enclosure). Data on the drive will not affect the response at all.

Comment: @TomYan Well, no, I don't think that's what I'm looking at. The sector count of the two partitions in the GPT of the working drive (when in the dock) sums to the sector count in the "Disk /dev/sdb:" field when it's in the enclosure, which is excluding the offset of 2048. I'm getting no indication that that field refers to PMBR values. Some kind of coincidence there? I don't know...

Comment: Well, `5552 = 1953525168 % 2048 + 4096` and `4144 = 976773168 % 2048 + 4096`. (Not that `4096` here is a number of 512-byte blocks, i.e. 2MiB, not a number of bytes.) While we got the math, we still have no idea what exactly it's doing behind the scene, let alone "fixing" it...

Comment: @TomYan Thanks for figuring out the math! I was meaning to look at it more closely (because mystery) but these late night experiments always left me mentally exhausted. This problem isn't technically part of this Q anymore though so I can ask a new one if it should need fixing; knowing the math is useful in itself since it's now possible to conclude that there's system behind the discrepancy, and not error.

Answer (score 2):

WD enclosures adjust the block/sector size that is presented to the OS. The structure is known as Advanced Format.

The long & short of this is that you may need to reformat a drive if you add it to the enclosure after formatting elsewhere, or the sector emulation doesn't map properly to the drive itself.

See [WD - Advanced Format White Paper](https://documents.westerndigital.com/content/dam/doc-library/en_us/assets/public/western-digital/collateral/white-paper/white-paper-advanced-format.pdf)

Note: No jumper adjustment should be necessary to use as a consumer drive, the factory setting is sufficient.

Comment: Although the LBA numbers would become invalid, the partition table should still be visible in this case though, IIRC. More precisely *logical* block size of 4096 bytes was coined the term AF *4Kn*. (Both 512e and 4Kn are considered / part of AF.)

Comment: @TomYan - but was this also true the 15 or so years ago that these components were new?

Comment: Except the drive is behaving differently to others of the same model, and per the link in my answer the jumpers are not related to advanced format...

Comment: Sure, the very reason AF 512e existed was because AF 4Kn requires support from the OSes and even in some cases userspace programs. The real "essence" of AF is the change of physical block size (or "sector" size, as in the actual sectors in the spinning drives; which is why IMO AF is sort of an outdated term, since while you can "format" / choose the logical block size (among 512 and 4096, at least) in most if not all NVMe SSD, using the term AF for them kind of makes no sense.

Comment: We could see what happens if the OP reformats...

Comment: @Tetsujin; repartitions, right?

Comment: "Although the LBA numbers would become invalid, the partition table should still be visible" - sure, but it would not point to correct location, assume LBA 2048, then 4K factor, it should point at LBA 16384 to find volume boot block.

Comment: Ok, I've read the white paper and the wiki article on AF, but have to conclude I don't know enough about the abstractions of USB or SATA to figure things out. I couldn't even find out how to determine whether the drive is native 4K or 512e! I will assume that software queries aren't useful here whatsoever — `fdisk -l` tells me both "logical" and "physical" sector sizes are 512, using an internal SATA connection. Meanwhile a price comparison site (only source I could find) tells me the drive is "512e" which implies a physical sector size of 4096...

Comment: @Andreas It doesn't matter anyway. The point here is just whether the enclosure "groups" 512-byte logical blocks into 4096-byte logical blocks. If you want to know that, just plug in the working identical drive to it and see if the logical block size changes to 4096. The thing is I/O error is not what you would get if that were the issue. I don't have an explanation for your case. The only thing I can think of is bad contact that somehow exists just between the non-working drive+enclosure, or may be some persistent setting in the drive like ATA password. Maybe check `dmesg` and `hdparm -I`.

Comment: @TomYan Ok, thank you. I thought that if I could confirm that the drive was already 4K native that there wouldn't be much sense for an enclosure to abstract away 512-byte blocks into 4096-byte blocks, but as long as my understanding is lacking I can't draw such conclusions. I've added the info you've suggested in the question.

Comment: @TomYan I can only agree with your conclusion that it points to an electrical or drive firmware issue. I've reseated the drive PCB, cleaned all contacts with alcohol and measured continuity of every SATA pin between drive and USB adapter. That leaves firmware, in my mind. Well, that might be the end of the road. I don't remember what, if any, platter-specific data is actually stored on the PCB so I don't think I'll make a board swap just for fun at this point. They both work everywhere else after all.

Answer (score -1):

Some Modern WD enclosures (eg. MyBook) will only work with the original hard drive, wd prevents us from re-using the enclosures. Here is an example of how to modify the enclosure to accept any hard drive, these hacks are specific to each model so do research on your specific model.>>>
https://www.youtube.com/watch?v=BpqlOB1AzCQ

Comment: “Modern WD enclosures (eg. MyBook) will only work with the original hard drive.” Not 100% true; _some_ modern WD enclosures need to be “hacked” to allow any drive to be used.

Comment: That sounds like a practice I wouldn't approve of. I might take a look later, but I've already verified that this enclosure can read other drives — I've even installed Debian through it on a drive I salvaged from a TV recorder box.

Answer (score -2):

I posit that there may be a jumper setting on the drive that needs to be changed - I guess check the working drive and compare!

That drive does have a place for jumpers on the back of the drive next to the SATA connector.  See https://crowdxaser.weebly.com/blog/western-digital-wd10eads-jumper-settings

Comment: I don't know the details of the features controlled by the jumper pins, so for all I know your answer may be a valid observation, so thanks for the suggestion. Maybe the downvoters have more in-depth knowledge about that. In this case there's no jumper on any drive though.

Answer (score -3):

There's likely a jumper on the hard drive that's set to master or slave and you already have the other drive set. Normally there's also an Auto jumper on most hard drives, at least on older models. I've have similar problems in the past with drives and it turned out to be those jumpers.

Also have a look through the motherboard manual as you may find you need to set different jumpers on the mother board.

CB

Comment: Master/Slave is only relevant for IDE, which is deprecated for more than a decade, not for SATA.